# Finding closest ancestor

Tags: javascript

I got a problem that I'm trying to figure out, was hoping someone can help. The input is something like this:

```
{
    "John": ["Sam", "Megan"],
    "Sam": ["Donna", "Josh", "Flora"],
    "Megan": ["Stephanie", "Nathan"]
}
```

Where Sam and Megan are John's children, etc. I'm required to find the closest ancestor of 2 names. For example, Sam and Josh will return Sam, Donna and Josh will return Sam, etc. I have completed that part, however the problem is if they start to move the structure around, so instead of above, they change it to:

```
{
    "Sam": ["Donna", "Josh", "Flora"],
    "Megan": ["Stephanie", "Nathan"],
    "John": ["Sam", "Megan"]
}
```

then my code has trouble with it. Can someone give me some sort of hints on this? My JavaScript knowledge is very basic so if someone can help it'll be great.

Comment: Can you post your current code you've tried?

Comment: What exactly does "closest ancestor of 2 names" mean for this exercise?

Comment: Sam and Josh will not return Sam as Sam is not and never will be an ancestor of himself.

Comment: Sounds like your initial solution wasn't generic enough (and maybe contained hard-coded results). As a hint, think of this structure as a tree (like an ancestry tree). Also do some reading on Lowest Common Ancestor algorithms and concepts.

Comment: Here is my code which I wrote http://notepad.cc/share/IHiKfV7sDy I coded it assuming that everything will be arranged normally (parent,child1,child2, etc) where child1,2 are the children of parent and not (child1,child2,parent, child3, etc) where child1,2,3 are children of parent.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at lineage and family trees is literally examining a tree structure. As such, there are some similarities that can be taken advantage of. In a tree form, it would be depth. In this lineage model, it will be a generation number. Note that you were already doing this logically (based on index). Now you just need to make it concrete.

I am not sure what works best for how you are composing these. But when you know the order, that is when you need to either add that into the array or wrap this in an object.

*Array version*

```
{
 "Sam": [2,"Donna", "Josh", "Flora"],
 "Megan": [2,"Stephanie", "Nathan"],
 "John": [1,"Sam", "Megan"]
}
```

*Object version*

```
{
 "Sam": {"generation":2,"children":["Donna", "Josh", "Flora"]},
 "Megan": {"generation":2,"children":["Stephanie", "Nathan"]},
 "John": {"generation:1","children":["Sam", "Megan"]}
}
```

Or an even more preferable version would be to also assign some sort of unique identifier to the family line so that you can also distinguish between them.

```
{
 "Sam": {
  "family":"f31460e9",
  "generation":2,
  "children":["Donna", "Josh", "Flora"]
 },
 "Megan": {
  "family":"f31460e9",
  "generation":2,
  "children":["Stephanie", "Nathan"]},
 "John": {
  "family":"f31460e9",
  "generation:1",
  "children":["Sam", "Megan"]
 }
}
```

Comment: I realized that if this is in C++, I can most likely do it using arrays and such, but with my limited JS knowledge I wasn't too sure.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is based off of Lowest Common Ancestor algorithms which can be easily researched. It assumes that you know the name of the person at the root of the entire tree. It basically recursively searches the tree looking for the lowest node that contains both elements. [Here is a JSFiddle containing a few names.](http://jsfiddle.net/6f9kX/) Hope this helps.

```
function findAncestor(root, p1, p2) {
   if(!root)
      return "";

   if(root == p1 || root == p2)
      return root;
   else
   {
      var count = 0;
      var lastfound = -1;
      if(fam[root]) //make sure root exists in fam
      {
          for(var i = 0; i < fam[root].length; i++)
          {
              var res = findAncestor(fam[root][i], p1, p2); //recursively search trees
              if(res)
              {
                  count++;
                  lastfound = i;
              }
          }
      }

      if(count >= 2) //found in different subtrees so this is the ancestor
         return root;
      else if(count == 1)
          return fam[root][lastfound];
      else
          return "";
   }
}
```